# Mapping two entities via @OneToMany relationship fails in Struts2 action

Tags: java, spring, jpa, struts2, entitymanager

Assume a product can have a list of accounts, the relationship between product and account is `@OneToMany`. In product class, I have created a Set interface to store accounts.
Next, I have made a method using Struts 2 to add accounts to a product. Each time I run this method, **the `HashSet` is reset and objects are removed from it**. Below, you can find the `DefaultProduct` class.

```
@Entity
public class DefaultProduct {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
Long id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "product", targetEntity = DefaultAccount.class)
private final Set<Account> accounts = new HashSet<Account>();

public DefaultProduct(Long id, Set<Account> accounts) {
    Assert.notEmpty(accounts);
    this.accounts.addAll(accounts);
}
// Getters 
}
```

The Struts 2 action method calls `editProduct()` method from the `service` class, which is Dependency Injected using Spring framework. The `service` class does not have any issues as this has been accurately tested. Below you can find methods from `service` class and Struts 2.

Service:

```
@Transactional
public void editProduct(Product product) {
   entityManager.merge(product);
}
```

Struts 2:

```
public String addAccount(){
   Set<Account> accounts = new HashSet<Account>();
   accounts.add(coreService.findAccountById(accountId));
   coreService.editProduct(new DefaultProduct(id, accounts));
   System.out.println(coreService.findProductById(id).getAccounts().size()); //Size-check
   return SUCCESS;
}
```

*Note:* Product is an interface implemented by `DefaultProduct` class.

Many thanks

Comment: You are not adding accounts to a product.

Comment: How can I do it Roman? The product constructor takes the passed Set and adds it to the existing one.. Is there something wrong?

Comment: yes, but you are not creating any product.

Comment: Roman sorry, I have miss-typed when I was writing the question.

Comment: So, what is the problem? The service didn't work?

Comment: Whenever I am trying to add an account to product, the added account stays in the the product's HashSet just during the addAccount() method . Later when I am calling another action method which displays all the added accounts, it returns empty. Thanks for being responsive Roman!

Comment: How do you know if it's the same product?

Comment: In my program I have an id variable which is auto-generated and serves as identity of each product. You caught me again on a miss-type as I did not include the id variable according to which the product is updated in my question. The id variable is mapped with the input variable in .jsp and passed inside addAccount() method.

Comment: You didn't use any generator and a strategy used to generate id involves getting id from the entity persisted to the database.

Comment: What do you mean Roman? The program generates ids for each persisted object, I have checked this in mysql.

Comment: The program generate nothing until you use a generator. And you did wrong by adding id to the constructor of the entity. The id is available after the session flushed.

Comment: When creating a product I use a no-arg constructor. The constructor with an id-arg is used after retrieving the id of the product I want to update. Btw, what represent the values filled by the program in my ID column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you have to add to one-to-many association is cascade type.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "product", targetEntity = DefaultAccount.class, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
private final Set<Account> accounts = new HashSet<Account>();
```

Comment: Thank you for the proposed solution Roman, but unfortunately the program still does not work. For some reason the added account is removed from the product's HashSet when calling another action method.

Comment: I have posted the method from my service class which is responsible for merging objects. Apart from this, it does persist, remove, find objects without any issues.

Comment: If you want to persist the you should use the appropriate method.

Comment: I do not want to persist the object Roman. Initially I create a product obj with a no-arg constructor, JPA generates an ID for it and stores it in the db. Then, I decide to add accounts to this product, so I find this product using it's ID and then use the constructor above to add the new Set with accounts.

Comment: Firstly you persist a product without accounts, them add accounts and update foreign key.

Comment: Yes that's right Roman, firstly I persist a product w/o accounts and a primary key is generated. Then I use the generated primary key to get a reference to the product obj and add accounts to it.. But this method fails

Comment: Thos accounts belong to other product and should be updated before you add them.

Comment: Roman, I have made changes according to your last comment and the program works now! Many thanks to you!